# Angular POST route not connecting to Nodejs for Stripe integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http

I'm integrating the Stripe checkout in my web app. I've implemented Stripe checkout on the angular front end and have also created a backend that is supposed to receive the token passed by stripe checkout. Upon submission of the stripe checkout form, my POST http request is not passing data to the backend. Although I get a 200 status from Stripe, I get no response for my nodejs.

Here is my checkout method invoked by a form.

```
 openCheckout() {
    let total = (this.donation * 100);
    let handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'key_test',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: (token: any) => {
        const transaction = new Charge(total, token.id);
        console.log('From navbar nonObject ' + token.id + ' ' + total);
        console.log(transaction + ' From navbar');
        this.keyService.charge(transaction);
      }
    });
    handler.open({
      name: 'Delaware March for Jesus',
      description: 'Donation',
      amount: total
    });
    this.donation = 0;
    this.donationEmail = '';
  }
```

Here is my Service code that implements the charge and passes the token to the backend.

```
charge(transaction: Charge) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(transaction);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
      return this.http.post(this.keysUrlDev + '/charge', body, { headers: headers })
          .map((response: Response) => response.json())
          .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

A simple angular model I constructed for transactions.

```
export class Charge {
  constructor(public amount: number,
              public token: string) {}
}
```

And my POST route on nodejs that takes the token and passes it through the stripe library charge.create method.

```
router.post('/charge', function(req, res, next) {
  var amount = req.body.amount;
  var token = req.body.token;
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Delaware March For Jesus Donation',
    source: token
  }, function(err, charge) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(req.body.amount + ' From POST' + req.body.token);
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error occured',
        error: err
      });
    }
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Charged successfully',
      obj: charge
    });
  });
});
```

I've gotten the token from the front end and sent a POST request via Postman successfully. Which logs the successful transaction and shows it in my stripe account. But, none of that happens when sending the request via angular.

I've used console.log to trace where the code stops and I can retrieve the token and amount in the keyService charge method. So it must be http.post that is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same type of issue almost exactly, and the change that made this work for me was to remove the InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService), and build the API into my express backend as a straightforward cut-and-paste. (I originally used the Angular 'Heroes' tutorial, and the in-memory API was implemented there.)

If I understand the issue broadly, it is that this in-memory API took over from the regular functioning of Angular's HTTP. Once released it functioned normally again - though I can't be more technically specific.

I hope it works for you too.